# Cannot parse Firebase url. Please use https://<YOUR FIREBASE>.firebaseio.com

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

While i click on the login button i get this error :

```
[19:49:11] [2018-12-25T20:49:57.389Z]  @firebase/database:, FIREBASE 
FATAL ERROR: Cannot parse Firebase url. Please use https://<YOUR 
FIREBASE>.firebaseio.com
- node_modules/@firebase/logger/dist/index.cjs.js:69:32 in 
defaultLogHandler
- node_modules/@firebase/logger/dist/index.cjs.js:159:31 in error
- node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.cjs.js:333:20 in fatal
- node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.cjs.js:1256:14 in 
parseRepoInfo
- node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.cjs.js:15103:38 in 
refFromURL
* src/modules/auth/api.js:24:24 in getUser
* src/modules/auth/api.js:19:32 in <unknown>
- node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.js:17:105 in <unknown>
- node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.js:20:199 in Fb
- ... 13 more stack frames from framework internals
```

I copied and pasted the config stuff directly from Firebase, so it should be correct, but I get this error anyway. What could be causing this? Is there any way the URL I'm copying from my database could be wrong somehow?

As you you can see in the error shown are in my file api.js in

```
.then((user) => getUser(user, callback))
```

and in

```
database.refFromURL('users').child(user.uid).once('value')
```

So here is my code from api.js is like this :

```
import { auth, database, provider } from "../../config/firebase";

export function register(data, callback) {
    const { email, password } = data;
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((user) => callback(true, user, null))
        .catch((error) => callback(false, null, error));
}

export function createUser (user, callback) {
   database.refFromURL('users').child(user.uid).update({ ...user })
        .then(() => callback(true, null, null))
        .catch((error) => callback(false, null, {message: error}));
}

export function login(data, callback) {
    const { email, password } = data;
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((user) => getUser(user, callback))
        .catch((error) => callback(false, null, error));
}

export function getUser(user, callback) {
    database.refFromURL('users').child(user.uid).once('value')
        .then(function(snapshot) {

            const exists = (snapshot.val() !== null);

            if (exists) user = snapshot.val();

            const data = { exists, user }
            callback(true, data, null);
        })
        .catch(error => callback(false, null, error));
}
```

can anyone please help where i missed up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i used

```
database.ref(`users/`+user.uid).once('value')
```

instead of

```
database.refFromURL('users').child(user.uid).once('value')
```

and it works fine for me now.

Answer (score 2):

Please go through this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup?hl=en#add-sdks-initialize) and update to new modular type or if you want to use old structure then, update to

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.5.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.5.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.5.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.5.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>
```

update all to version 8.5.0. Will work flawless

Answer (score 0):

The `refFromURL` method expects a fully qualified URL to the database. So something starting with `https://<YOUR 
FIREBASE>.firebaseio.com` as the error message shows.

You're trying to access a path within the configured database, in which case you should use `ref(...)` instead:

```
database.ref('users').child(user.uid).once('value')
```

Comment: when i use database.ref instead of database. refFromURL, i get another error which is : Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "undefined". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"

Comment: That means you have disallowed characters in the path. Calling `refFromURL` is not the solution in that case, because it has a completely different purpose (as I explained above). Rather, figure out where those characters come from, and replace them. If you search for the error message, you'll find quite some previous questions on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are mainly two types of realtime db urls , one ends with ".firebaseio.com" which is for US and other like EU and asia have url which ends with "firebasedatabase.app"

"Please use https://.firebaseio.com", this error comes at line when u call firebase.database(), It can happen that firebase library or module you are using are of old versions which can only make call for db whose url ends with firebaseio.com,
so make sure to update it,

or you can just change the region of your realtime database to US region.